# How to call a goal and bind the number of logical inferences to a variable in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

According to the manual, `time(+Goal)` executes `Goal` and prints, amongst other things, the number of logical inferences used.

How can I bind the number of logical inferences to a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code is specific to SWI-Prolog. Currently, many other Prologs do not permit to count the number of inferences, mainly due to many different optimizations that would blur that number.

```
:- meta_predicate(call_inferences(0, -)).

call_inferences(Goal_0, Inferences) :-
   statistics(inferences, I0),
   Goal_0,
   statistics(inferences, I1),
   Inferences is I1-I0-1.
```

Usage:

```
?- call_inferences(true,N).
   N = 1.
?- call_inferences(nreverse([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30],L), N).
   L = [30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22|...], N = 496.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can 'install' an hook for several system interfaces, among them the [message_hook](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=message_hook/3), just declaring it in module user. Now, filter for `Kind=information` and `Term=time(NumInferences,_,_,_)` and store it in a [global variable](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nb_setval/2).